# How to retrieve object attributes of an OneToOneField relation in Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to extend the User model with a OneToOneField, so I can add more fields to a user:

```
class Userattribs(models.Model):    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    passcode = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # about user
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
```

I also have the following model serializers:

```
class UserattribsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    class Meta:
        model = Userattribs

        fields = ('organisation', 'description')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userattribs = UserattribsSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields =('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'userattribs')
```

The problem I'm having is the serialisation of a User, does not include the 'userattribs' in the json response. I've spent hours googling and banging my head. I'd be eternally grateful if you help me out.

Thanks in advance!

I've added the views. One odd thing I noticed was that when I queried (using UserList) all data, I would get the Userattribs. However, when I retrieve a single item, I don't get the Userattribs

```
###################################################
### Views #########################################
###################################################
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (access_permission,)
```

Comment: add your `urls.py` and outputs of `UserDetail`view please. What is this `access_permission` variable? Comment permission_classes to debug

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error in your code. Are you sure that your `User` objects have an `Userattribs` object.

Open your python shell with `python manage.py shell` and enter this to test your code :

```python
#import your related models and serializer
from your_app.models import *
from your_app.serializer import *
# create new user
user = User.objects.create(username="test")
# create new user attrib linked to `user` object
user_attrib = Userattribs.objects.create(user=user, organisation="DJANGO")
# serialize your `user` object
user_serializer = UserSerializer(user)
# display your serialized data
user_serializer.data
# outputs : {'last_name': '', 'userattribs': OrderedDict([('organisation', 'DJANGO'), ('description', None)]), 'email': '', 'username': 'test', 'first_name': '', 'id': 3}
```

If it ok, the problem maybe come from your view.

Comment: Massive thanks for responding Louis. I did as instructed and it all seems to work :/ 
I suspect it maybe something to do with serializers but it looks correct to me.

    class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

        queryset = User.objects.all()

        serializer_class = UserSerializer

        permission_classes = (access_permission,)

Comment: your welcome. :) Add your view to your question, please.

Comment: Thanks for helping Louis. I've updated the post with the views I have